# Beginner debugging a function

Tags: python, function, debugging

Hi, I am doing an online tutorial for python on codeacademy and i already created a functional pyg latin translator that uses raw_input and turns it into a word in pyglatin, however, when I try to turn this translator into a function that takes a word and returns a word in pyg latin I get an error. Is there a fundamental difference in the way these work?

**Here is the functional translator:**

```
original = raw_input("Enter a word in English to translate to Pyg Latin:")

vowels = ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"]

if len(original) > 0 and original.isalpha():
    word = original.lower() 
    if word[0] in vowels:
        translation = word + "ay"
        print translation
    else:
        translation = word[1:] + word[0] + "ay"
        print translation
else:
    print "This is not a valid entry! Please try again."

# Here is the function that comes up with an error:

vowels = ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"]

def pyglatin(eng):
    if eng.isalpha() and len(eng) > 0:
        word = eng.lower()
        if word[0] in vowels:
            return word + "ay"
        else:
            return word[1:] + word[0] + "ay"
    else:
        return False
```

When I try and call the function and type pyglatin(ant) for example to see the translation of the word ant, I get this error:

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "", line 1, in 
    pyglatin(ant)
NameError: name 'ant' is not defined

Please note that all of the indenting is correct, but I may not have shown the correct spacing here. I really just want to know if there's a fundamental problem with my logic.
Thanks!!!

Comment: What error are you getting? Post the full traceback. Your function looks good, so it's probably somewhere else in your code.

Comment: It probably won't fix your problem, but a few suggestions: `vowels = ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"]` can be replaced with `vowels = "aeiou"` since each list item is just one character long. `len(eng) > 0` can be replaced with `eng` since a string is truthy if its length is greater than zero and falsy otherwise.

Comment: @icktoofay - it's even simpler than that: `eng.isalpha()` returns false if the string is empty, so that's the only test needed there.

Comment: The only real difference between the function version and the original code is the order of the tests in the first `if` statement. But that doesn't matter, because `eng.isalpha()` really does both those tests for you anyway, so they do the same thing. It would help to see how you *call* the function, of course. Can you provide a complete example?

Comment: Thanks for the help. Here's the error to be more specific. When I try and call the function and type pyglatin(ant) for example to see the translation of the word ant, I get this error:    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    pyglatin(ant)
NameError: name 'ant' is not defined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> File "", line 1, in pyglatin(ant) NameError: name 'ant' is not defined

`pyglatin(ant)` means run it on the variable `ant`, which is undefined. To pass in a literal string, use quotes:

```
pyglatin('ant')
```

There are [many more ways](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#literals) to represent literal strings in Python, but this is the simplest and most obvious.

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to know, without knowing what the error is that you are getting. Though perhaps: could the problem be that in the global scope of your program you are not assigning the `return ...` to anything? What do I mean by this? An example:

```
def hello():
    return 'Hello, world!'

hello()
```

output:  there is nothing to output in this case, because you have not provided any measn to reference the return value of `hello()`. But, if you were to do the following:

```
print(hello())
--> Hello, world!

greeting = hello()
print(greeting)
--> Hello, world!
```

The first example, print the return statement from `hello()`, and the second assigns the return value to a variable, giving you a means to reference it again.